# how to remove these errors ora-31640 and ora-39001,ora-39000 and ora-27041

Tags: oracle11gr2

[image: these error occured when I am trying to import dump file.]

i have only dump file so i cant recreate the another dump file.
how to solver these error?

Answer (score 0):

In the image that you posted your current directory is `C:\Users\Vattamwar`, which is where it appears that the dump file is located. However, as shown in the ORA-31640 message, the IMPDP utility expects the dumpfile to be located in the directory `D:\app\oracle\admin\xe\dpdump`. I suggest that you move your dump file `dream.dmp` to the directory `D:\app\oracle\admin\xe\dpdump`.